# Activity Indicator startAnimating before NSURL Call

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a method that accesses my site via NSURL. This works very well, but I would like to have an activity indicator that displays while the web call is being processed.

My issue is that the activity indicator does not appear until after the NSURL call has finished. I have tried including the two bits of code that make my activity indicator appear at the very top of the method (please see below). Im sure there's something that has to do with when the UI gets updated, but I do not know how to handle this. All I want is for the activity indicator to start animating and for the loadingImageView to appear right away. Any help would be great. Thank you!

```
- (IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender {    

//ACTIVITY INDICATOR STARTS WITH THESE TWO LINES
loadingImageView.hidden = false;
[activityIndicator startAnimating];

NSString *c = [view.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
NSString *b = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"b"];
NSString *a = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"a"];

NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/page.php?
a=%@&b=%@&c=%@",a, b, c];

NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL 
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog (@"%@", strResult);

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"true" forKey:@"newKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) for calling your URL in background like bellow as per your code:-

```
  loadingImageView.hidden = false;
  [activityIndicator startAnimating];

__Block NSString *c = [view.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
__Block NSString *b = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"b"];
__Block NSString *a = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"a"];

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

         NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/page.php?a=%@&b=%@&c=%@",a, b, c];
         NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
         NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         NSLog (@"%@", strResult);

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"true" forKey:@"newKey"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be working very well, but i ended up removing the "__Block" from the beginning of each of the NSStrings up at the top. It seems to be working fine without those __Block parts. Is it OK that I removed those or will it cause me a problem later?

Comment: i dont think this is prob later you can use this string variable inside *dispatch_async* currect me if i am wrong

Answer (score 2):

You should put your network code in a background queue, otherwise the UI will freeze, just like you're experiencing right now

You could do something like

```
NSOperationQueue *backgroundQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[backgroundQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    //Your network code
}];
```

Comment: can you perhaps help me with an example?

Comment: so I could literally just wrap all the network code in that block?

Comment: Yes. Then in that same block you can call a method on self to notify that you finished downloading the data. Just remember that if you have to update your UI from the background, you have to call  `performSelectorOnMainThread:` or you can also call `[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:]` or you can call `dispatch_async` passing `dispatch_get_main_queue()`

Answer (score 2):

The `+[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` method is synchronous: this means it blocks until the data transfer is complete. You *never* want to do this on the main thread as the UI blocks during the data transfer.

So you should either move the data transfer to another thread, for example by using wrapping it in a method and calling that using `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(foo) withObject:nil]` or using GCD:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Insert netword code here.

    // Once done, resume on the main thread:
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Code to update the UI or something.
    });
});
```

Another way to solve this issue is to use the asynchronous data transfer, for example using [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE).